# How to speed up openmp parallel for with ordered clause?

Tags: c++, openmp

I have tried to parallelize a for loop of some sequential c++ code with openmp. The difficulty lies in the right treatment of

```
linkingVarVals
```

To receive the same results as in the sequential code, I have used the ordered clause of openmp. The following approach seems to work in my case. But unfortunatly the openmp code is actually slower than the sequential execution. Presumably this is caused by the ordered clause. Is there any way in my case to speedup the openmp implementation?

```
typedef tuple<int,int,int> key3;
struct key3_hash : public std::unary_function<key3, std::size_t> {
    std::size_t operator()(const key3& k) const {
        return std::get<0>(k) ^ std::get<1>(k) ^ std::get<2>(k);
    }
};

struct key3_equal : public std::binary_function<key3, key3, bool> {
    bool operator()(const key3& v0, const key3& v1) const {
        return (std::get<0>(v0) == std::get<0>(v1) &&
        std::get<1>(v0) == std::get<1>(v1) &&
        std::get<2>(v0) == std::get<2>(v1));
    }
};

 typedef tuple<int,int> key2;
 struct key2_hash : public std::unary_function<key2, std::size_t> {
     std::size_t operator()(const key2& k) const {
         return std::get<0>(k) ^ std::get<1>(k);
     }
 };

 struct key2_equal : public std::binary_function<key2, key2, bool> {
     bool operator()(const key2& v0, const key2& v1) const {
         return (std::get<0>(v0) == std::get<0>(v1) &&
                 std::get<1>(v0) == std::get<1>(v1));
     }
 };

typedef unordered_map<key3, double, key3_hash, key3_equal> CoeffMap;
typedef unordered_map<key3, GRBVar, key3_hash, key3_equal> VarMap;
typedef unordered_map<key2, double, key2_hash, key2_equal> ValueMap;
typedef unordered_map<key3, GRBConstr, key3_hash, key3_equal> ConstrMap;

void myalgorithm(GRBModel model,
const vector<GRBModel*>& submips,
const set<string>& linkingvarnames,
const map<string,int>& nametoidxmap,
const map<int,string>& idxtonamemap,
const map<int,set<int> >& linkvaridxtoblock,
const map<int,set<int> >& blocktolinkvaridx)
{
    size_t nBlocks = submips.size();
    size_t nVars = model.get(GRB_IntAttr_NumVars);
    CoeffMap slackPosCoeffs;
    CoeffMap slackNegCoeffs;
    VarMap slackPosVars;
    VarMap slackNegVars;
    ValueMap linkingVarVals;
    ConstrMap couplingCons;

    // the following code shows the connection between 
    // submips[block] and couplingCons
    for (size_t block = 0; block < nBlocks; ++block) {
        set<int> linkVarsInBlock = blocktolinkvaridx.at(block);
        for (set<int>::const_iterator it = linkVarsInBlock.begin(), ei = linkVarsInBlock.end(); it != ei; ++it) {
            int linkVarIdx = *it;
            set<int> blocksContainingLinkVar = linkvaridxtoblock.at(linkVarIdx);
            for (set<int>::const_iterator jt = blocksContainingLinkVar.begin(), ej = blocksContainingLinkVar.end(); jt != ej; ++jt) {
                int blockContainingLinkVar = *jt;
                if (blockContainingLinkVar != block) {
                    auto idx2 = make_tuple(blockContainingLinkVar, linkVarIdx);
                    auto idx3 = make_tuple(block, blockContainingLinkVar, linkVarIdx);
                    stringstream constrName;
                    constrName << idxtonamemap.at(linkVarIdx) << "_Coupling_Block_" << blockContainingLinkVar;
                    couplingCons[idx3] = submips[block]->addConstr(submips[block]->getVarByName(idxtonamemap.at(linkVarIdx)) + slackPosVars.at(idx3) - slackNegVars.at(idx3) == linkingVarVals.at(idx2), constrName.str());
                }
            }
        }
        submips[block]->update();
    }

#if defined(_OPENMP)
    // set number of openmp threads
    unsigned int numprocs = omp_get_num_procs();
    cout << "=== NumProcessors " << numprocs << endl;
    unsigned int numthreads = numprocs > 1 ? numprocs :        
    std::min((int)nBlocks, 4);
    omp_set_num_threads(numthreads);
    cout << "=== OpenMP threads " << numthreads << endl;
#endif

    double newRHS;
#pragma omp parallel for ordered schedule(dynamic)
    // 1. loop
    for (size_t block = 0; block < nBlocks; ++block) {
        set<int> linkVarsInBlock = blocktolinkvaridx.at(block);

        // 2. loop
        for (set<int>::const_iterator it = linkVarsInBlock.begin(), ei = linkVarsInBlock.end(); it != ei; ++it) {
            int linkVarIdx = *it;
            set<int> blocksContainingLinkVar = linkvaridxtoblock.at(linkVarIdx);

            // 3. loop
            for (set<int>::const_iterator jt = blocksContainingLinkVar.begin(), ej = blocksContainingLinkVar.end(); jt != ej; ++jt) {
                int blockContainingLinkVar = *jt;
                if (blockContainingLinkVar != block) {
                    auto idx3 = make_tuple(block, blockContainingLinkVar, linkVarIdx);
                    auto idx2 = make_tuple(blockContainingLinkVar, linkVarIdx);
                    GRBConstr c = couplingCons.at(idx3);
                    string name = c.get(GRB_StringAttr_ConstrName);
                    double oldRHS = c.get(GRB_DoubleAttr_RHS);
#pragma omp ordered
                    {
                        newRHS = linkingVarVals.at(idx2);
                    }
                    c.set(GRB_DoubleAttr_RHS, newRHS);

                    slackPosVars.at(idx3).set(GRB_DoubleAttr_Obj, slackPosCoeffs.at(idx3));
                    slackNegVars.at(idx3).set(GRB_DoubleAttr_Obj, slackNegCoeffs.at(idx3));
                }
            }
        }

        submips[block]->optimize();

        // 4. loop
        for (set<int>::const_iterator it = linkVarsInBlock.begin(), ei = linkVarsInBlock.end(); it != ei; ++it) {
            int linkVarIdx = *it;
            auto idx2 = make_tuple(block, linkVarIdx);

            linkingVarVals[idx2] = submips[block]->getVarByName(idxtonamemap.at(linkVarIdx)).get(GRB_DoubleAttr_X);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On first glance it looks like you execute multiple ordered regions per OMP iteration. That is illegal. Each iteration in an ordered OMP loop may execute at most one OMP ordered region.

Comment: It is unclear from your code though why/how you need the ordered region. What type does `linkingVarVals` have? Are you modifying anything on the reference it gives you? How is the access order important (and is it even thread-safe)? It would help if you could add declarations for all the variables you use (and possibly switch to range-based for loops because right now those loops are a lot of unnecessary noise).

Comment: Please narrow down your code to a [mcve]. Right now you show way too little to give specific advise how to resolve your ordering problem.

Comment: As it stands your code is full of race conditions, with or without the ordered region. In fact, the ordered region does essentially nothing at all - why do you share a double between the threads and then (partially) synchronize access instead of giving each thread a local `double newrhs`? How are you using `newrhs`? What does any of this have to do with the code after the parallel loop?

Comment: Maybe there are race conditions, but I have tested more than 100 instances and the results are the same as for the sequential code. In the sequential code linkingVarVals is updated in a specific order and I tried to recreate this order by the ordered clause. Actually, I need a kind of a barrier for all threads behind 4. loop. But within parallel for a barrier clause is not allowed.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but you cannot conclude from "it runs fine" to "it's correct". Even with your edit, the code is unfortunately very far from a [mcve] - please read the page very carefully.

Comment: That's right - the test is no proof! The newrhs has influence on the solving of submips[block]->optimize(). What can I do to avoid race conditions in my code and using a barrier clause after 4. loop?

Comment: We can't tell you. The most important part, namely everything between `newrhs = ...` and `optimize()`, is missing. Again: As it stands, the ordered region does nothing (and is illegal = undefined behaviour because you have more than one ordered region per OMP iteration) and you most likely have a race condition on `newrhs` because it is shared between threads without proper synchronization. Numbering your loops does nothing to help. Your example is _maybe_ 50% of the way to being sufficient.

Comment: I have now posted the complete code except the main function. You can see everything and can compile it with g++ -fopenmp and libgurobi. But I think it is not necessary to compile the code. For any useful hints I'm very grateful.

Comment: Still has no chance of compiling because the `block` in `submips[block]` does not exist. Is the `optimize` call supposed to be inside the loop?

Comment: Sorry, I interchanged one brace.

Comment: I added further code to understand the connection between submips[block] and couplingCons.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions that I am making because they are not evident from your sample:

- Each `block` (i.e. OMP iteration) has its own `GRBModel` and every `GRBConstr`, `GRBVar` etc. that you access has been associated with the correct model (the one from the same `block`) already.
- `libgurobi` safely allows concurrent operations on the above variables as long as they belong to different models.

Here are the issues with your code:

- There is absolutely no point in having `newRHS` shared between threads. All you do is read it and then immediately write it. Make it a local variable, you only get problems from having it shared.
- Some threads may be writing into `linkingVarVals` in loop 4 while other threads are reading from it in loop 3. Here it depends on your data.

  - Option a): Due to the way your `set`s are filled, the OMP iteration for block `block` only ever reads from `linkingVarVals.at({block, ...})`, never any other block. In this case things are easy: You must ensure that the `linkingVarVals` map is never reallocated by the writes in loop 4 (i.e. no entries are created by `operator[]` - just create all entries beforehand) and you must ensure that those writes happen in the serial order (place the ordered region around the entire loop 4).
  - Option b): The writes in loop 4 have an influence on the subsequent `newRHS = ...` reads. In that case this is hard if not impossible to parallelize because each OMP iteration can only start reading `linkingVarVals` once the previous OMP iteration is fully done writing to `linkingVarVals`. The dependencies would force the OMP iterations to be executed serially even with perfect synchronization.

I can't tell you which option it is or whether it's somewhere in the middle. It depends entirely on the values in your `linkVarsInBlock` and `blocksContainingLinkVar` sets. Maybe the blocks are completely independent. Maybe you have hundreds of interdepending blocks and some can be processed independently with clever distribution and synchronization. Or maybe each block depends on every preceding one so you cannot parallelize at all.

PS: Consider using range-based for loops. There is so much boilerplate overhead in your code from declaring, assigning and comparing iterators of containers when you just want to visit each contained object once. That is exactly what range-based for loops exist for and they would make your code that much more readable.

Comment: Option b) is my situation. But the instruction submips[block]->optimize() took in each iteration the majority of time. Thus it may still make sense to have a kind of a barrier behind 4. loop. How can I restructure my code to enable such an approach? Can you give me some pseudo code advice, which you recommend?

Comment: You cannot make the `optimize()` parallel if the input/setup (loop 3) in iteration `block = N` depends on the output/readout (loop 4) of `block = N-1`. Adding or removing barriers does not change that - your loop is inherently serial. You would have to change your algorithm. For example, you cannot parallelize the time steps of a simulation because each time step depends on the previous one - even if the simulation in each time step takes very long.